# In the last two years and currently — can I use this?

Tags: sentence-construction

> In the last two years I worked on some position at the company. And currently I do the same.

Can I use Present Simple 'In the last 2 years I work' and it will mean in the last two years and currently.

Or I have to use full expression like 'In the last two years and currently I work'

I need to mention that cause I was on another position before. And it's interesting to know how to avoid saying 'Since'

Comment: is this for a CV / Resumé or when you are talking face-to-face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is when the perfect continuous tense is ideal:

> I've been working in the HR department for two years.

It implies that you are currently working in HR, and gives the length of time.

Present perfect ("I've worked... for two years") is also possible.

There are lots of other ways to express this. For CVs (where you want to be concise)

> Mar 2018 - Present:  Working in HR.

Telling your life story (when you want to be long-winded)

> Well, I started in HR back in 2018 and, two years later, I'm still in the same department, but...

Comment: Thank you, James!